# Azure AD B2C User flow with MSAL in .NET MAUI App - Generic sign in served instead of respecting user flow

Tags: azure, maui, azure-ad-b2c

I cannot figure out why the app continues to show the generic microsoft sign in screen rather than showing the screen associated with the user flow in B2C.

I have the client id, tenant id, redirect uri and authority set correctly.

When I mess with the authority, it will eventually throw an error if I deviate from the 3 parameters required, but altering the name of the user flow at the end has no effect; even if I set it to one that does not exist. Same generic login 100% of the time.

How can I get the correct user flow to load (I'm implementing a signup/signin)?

```
 public class MsalAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
    {
        private string _accessToken = string.Empty;
        private bool _isLoggedIn = false;
        public bool IsLoggedIn
        {
            get { return _isLoggedIn; }
            private set { _isLoggedIn = value; } //TODO: Need to implement a messenger service (publisher/subscriber) to have on change event
        }

        private PCAWrapper PCAWrapper;
        public MsalAuthenticationService(PCAWrapper pCAWrapper)
        {
           PCAWrapper = pCAWrapper;
        }
        public async Task<bool> LoginAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await PCAWrapper.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(PCAWrapper.Scopes).ConfigureAwait(false);
                IsLoggedIn = true;
                _accessToken = result.AccessToken;

                return IsLoggedIn;
            }
            catch(MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                var result = await PCAWrapper.AcquireTokenInteractiveAsync(PCAWrapper.Scopes);
                IsLoggedIn = true;
                _accessToken = result.AccessToken;

                return IsLoggedIn;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsLoggedIn = false;
                _accessToken = string.Empty;

                return IsLoggedIn;
            }
        }
        public async Task<bool> LogoutAsync()
        {
            await PCAWrapper.SignOutAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            IsLoggedIn = false;
            _accessToken = string.Empty;

            return !IsLoggedIn;
        }
    }
```

This line initiates the authenticate/authorize process: `await _msalAuthenticationService.LoginAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

The authority being used: https://xyz.b2clogin.com/tfp/xyz.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_FlowName

The actual call to azure:

```
internal async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenInteractiveAsync(string[] scopes)
        {

#if IOS
        // Hide the privacy prompt in iOS
        var systemWebViewOptions = new SystemWebViewOptions();
        systemWebViewOptions.iOSHidePrivacyPrompt = true;

        return await PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                .WithAuthority(Authority)
                                .WithTenantId(TenantId)
                                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(PlatformConfig.Instance.ParentWindow)
                                .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(UseEmbedded)
                                .WithSystemWebViewOptions(systemWebViewOptions)
                                .ExecuteAsync()
                                .ConfigureAwait(false);
#else
            return await PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                    .WithB2CAuthority(Authority)
                                    .WithTenantId(TenantId)
                                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(PlatformConfig.Instance.ParentWindow)
                                    .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                                    .ExecuteAsync()
                                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
#endif

            throw new Exception("Platform not supported.");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Define .WithB2CAuthority in the PublicClientApplicationBuilder instead of AcquireTokenInteractive.

This fixed my issue, but I'm not sure why it made a difference.